# How to pass a styled component with its children to another function so that I can create an enzyme mount wrapper helper function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, styled-components

I created a function `ScMountWithTheme` helper function and I want to just be able to pass this function two arguments, 1) the component(s) I am trying to render and 2) the children nested inside this component. The purpose is so that I don't have to rewrite code that mounts the same theme over and over.

I have tried passing it and accessing through children but that didn't seem to work. I tried to see what is on the actual component object that might help, but wasn't sure exactly would be useful.

The expected output is to pass the test, but currently I am not getting the proper response object from the wrapper.

```
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { getTheme } from "../../../src/components/framework/StyledComponents/themes";

export const ScMountWithTheme = (Component, mode) => {
  return mount(
    <ThemeProvider theme={getTheme(mode)}>{Component.children}</ThemeProvider>,
  );
};

describe.only("ScH1 Styled Component", () => {
  it("renders H1 with Test in the text", () => {
    const wrapper = ScMountWithTheme(<ScH1>Test</ScH1>, "BUY");
    expect(wrapper.find("h1").text()).toContain("Test");
  });
});
```